# Banshee Stopped Working

Tags: banshee, mono, dbus

Recently Banshee stopped working. Running it in the terminal gives me

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dbus-sharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5675b0c3093115b5' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'dbus-sharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5675b0c3093115b5'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dbus-sharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5675b0c3093115b5' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'dbus-sharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5675b0c3093115b5'`<br>
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling mono and banshee multiple times, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have libdbus1.0-cil installed, as that is the package that contains dbus-sharp-1.0.

```
apt-cache policy libdbus1.0-cil
```

If the first line reads `Installed: (none)`, install the package:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libdbus1.0-cil
```

If it is installed, reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall libdbus1.0-cil
```

Comment: running apt-cache gives `Installed: 0.7.0-5ubuntu1`.
I reinstalled the library, but no change. I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but I recently upgraded to mono 4.3 from the git repo. I've uninstalled and reinstalled it multiple times, so I don't know why it hasn't downgraded. Is there anything I could do to get the mono version form the Ubuntu repos?

Comment: I installed from source, I didn't have the repo enabled. Either way, I fixed it by reinstalling the OS.